# Who is the author of the Pirush on the first four chapters of Rambam's Hilchos Yesodei HaTorah?

Tags: jewish-books, rambam, commentaries, authorship

The first four chapters of Hilchos Yesodei HaTorah have a lengthy commentary that is titled simply "פירוש". In standard editions of the Rambam, it wraps around the text, facing the "כסף משנה" (see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39979&st=&pgnum=16) on the bottom right). It would appear that the work is of unknown authorship. The title page of the Shabsi Frankel edition simply describes it as "פירוש על ארבעה פרקים הראשונים של הלכות יסודי התורה".

My question is if anyone knows if there is any information on who the author of this work is? Has anyone attempted to identify the author? Have any theories been advanced?

Comment: By comparing the text of one of his comments, is it any of the ones listed here? http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam

Comment: @DoubleAA No, compare to [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39979&st=&pgnum=16). (Btw, when other commentaries mention it, they usually call it the "מפרש".)

Comment: We also have anonymous 'Peirush' to Rambam Kiddush Hachodesh http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14278&st=&pgnum=304

Comment: @DoubleAA True. Do you think they might be from the same person?

Comment: I have no reason to assume either way.

Comment: @DoubleAA If you read that Hakdama it says רבי עובדיה בן דוד

Comment: @GershonGold Good point!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Yeshurin 21 Page 65](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46427&st=&pgnum=65&hilite=) Rabbi Ezra Shaivet says that there are those who attribute it to רבי עובדיה בן דוד, however it is still unclear whether this is accurate. He does not indicate who it is that attributes this to the רבי עובדיה בן דוד.

Comment: He says some attribute it to רבי עובדיה בן דוד. As far as I know, this was not any of the three Ra'avads (especially considering that all of their names were אברהם). This is the same name as the commentator to Kidush HaChodesh (as you noted in your comment to the question).

Comment: At this point, I'm going to accept this answer. But if a better answer comes along, I might have to switch.