# Rambam on the relationship between oneness and incorporeality

Tags: rambam, theology, contradiction

One of Rambam's arguments for the existence of only one God is that the existence of multiple gods by definition implies some form of corporeality.

**Hilchos Yesodei HaTorah 1:7**

> אלוה זה אחד הוא ואינו שנים ולא יתר על שנים אלא אחד שאין כיחודו אחד מן
> האחדים הנמצאים בעולם לא אחד כמין שהוא כולל אחדים הרבה ולא אחד כגוף
> שהוא נחלק למחלקות ולקצוות אלא יחוד שאין יחוד אחר כמותו בעולם **אילו היו
> אלוהות הרבה היו גופין וגויות מפני שאין הנמנים השוין במציאותן נפרדין זה
> מזה אלא במאורעין שיארעו בגופות והגויות** ואילו היה היוצר גוף וגוייה היה
> לו קץ ותכלית שאי אפשר להיות גוף שאין לו קץ וכל שיש לגופו קץ ותכלית יש
> לכחו קץ וסוף ואלהינו ברוך שמו הואיל וכחו אין לו קץ ואינו פוסק שהרי
> הגלגל סובב תמיד אין כחו כח גוף והואיל ואינו גוף לא יארעו לו מאורעות
> הגופות כדי שיהא נחלק ונפרד מאחר לפיכך אי אפשר שיהיה אלא אחד וידיעת דבר
> זה מצות עשה שנאמר ה' אלהינו ה' אחד
>
> This God is one. He is not two or more, but one, unified in a manner
> which [surpasses] any unity that is found in the world; i.e., He is
> not one in the manner of a general category which includes many
> individual entities, nor one in the way that the body is divided into
> different portions and dimensions. Rather, He is unified, and there
> exists no unity similar to His in this world.
>
> **If there were many gods<sup>1</sup>, they would have body and form, because like
> entities are separated from each other only through the circumstances
> associated with body and form.**
>
> Were the Creator to have body and form, He would have limitation and
> definition, because it is impossible for a body not to be limited. And
> any entity which itself is limited and defined [possesses] only
> limited and defined power. Since our God, blessed be His name,
> possesses unlimited power, as evidenced by the continuous revolution
> of the sphere, we see that His power is not the power of a body. Since
> He is not a body, the circumstances associated with bodies that
> produce division and separation are not relevant to Him. Therefore, it
> is impossible for Him to be anything other than one.
>
> The knowledge of this concept fulfills a positive commandment, as
> [implied by Deuteronomy 6:4]: "[Hear, Israel,] God is our Lord, God is
> one." ([Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904960/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-One.htm))

However, when he discusses angels he asserts that they are also incorporeal, yet he states that there are many different angels.

**Hilchos Yesodei HaTorah 2:2-5**

> כל מה שברא הקב"ה בעולמו נחלק לשלשה חלקים מהן ברואים שהן מחוברים מגולם
> וצורה והם הווים ונפסדים תמיד כמו גופות האדם והבהמה והצמחים והמתכות
> ומהן ברואים שהן מחוברים מגולם וצורה אבל אינן משתנין מגוף לגוף ומצורה
> לצורה כמו הראשונים אלא צורתן קבועה לעולם בגולמם ואינן משתנין כמו אלו
> והם הגלגלים והכוכבים שבהן ואין גולמם כשאר גולמים ולא צורתם כשאר צורות
> **ומהן ברואים צורה בלא גולם כלל והם המלאכים שהמלאכים אינם גוף וגויה אלא צורות נפרדות זו מזו**
>
> ומהו זה שהנביאים אומרים שראו המלאך אש ובעל כנפים הכל במראה הנבואה ודרך
> חידה לומר שאינו גוף ואינו כבד כגופות הכבדים כמו שנאמר כי ה' אלהיך אש
> אוכלה הוא ואינו אש אלא משל וכמו שנאמר עושה מלאכיו רוחות
>
> **ובמה יפרדו הצורות זו מזו והרי אינן גופין לפי שאינן שוין במציאותן אלא כל אחד מהן למטה ממעלתו של חבירו והוא מצוי מכחו זה למעלה מזה** והכל
> נמצאים מכחו של הקדוש ברוך הוא וטובו וזהו שרמז שלמה בחכמתו ואמר כי גבוה
> מעל גבוה שומר
>
> Everything which the Holy One, blessed be He, created within His world
> is divided into three categories. They include:
>
> a) Creations which are a combination of matter and form. They are
> constantly coming into existence and ceasing to exist; for example,
> the bodies of man and beasts, plants, and metals.
>
> b) Creations which are [also] a combination of matter and form, but do
> not change from body to body and from form to form as those in the
> first category. Rather, their form is permanently fixed in their
> matter, and they do not change as the others do; for example, the
> spheres and the stars [which revolve] in them. The matter [from which]
> they [are composed] differs from [a simple conception of] matter, and
> their form differs from [a simple conception of] form.
>
> c) **Creations which have form, but no matter at all; for example, the
> angels, for the angels do not possess bodies or corporeal being, but
> rather are forms which are separate from each other.**
>
> What is meant by the prophets' statements that they saw an angel of
> fire or with wings? All these are prophetic visions and parables, as
> [Deuteronomy 4:24] states: "God, your Lord, is consuming fire," though
> He is not fire and [the description of Him in this manner] is only
> metaphoric. Similarly, [Psalms 104:4] states: "He makes His angels as
> winds...."
>
> **Since they possess no body, what separates the form [of the angels] from each other? Their existence is not alike. Rather each one is
> below the level of the other and exists by virtue of its influence,
> [in a progression of levels,] one above the other.**
>
> Everything exists by virtue of the influence of the Holy One, blessed
> be He, and His goodness. Solomon alluded to this [concept] in his
> wisdom, saying (Ecclesiastes 5:7): "Because above the one who is high
> there is a watcher [and there are others higher than them]." ([Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904962/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Two.htm))

Why is it that angels can be distinguished from each other without a physical manifestation, yet gods cannot be distinguished from each other without a physical manifestation?

Even if one were to argue, as does R. Elyahu Touger in his footnote to 1:7, that Rambam is even referring to "a spiritual sense of these concepts", it does not explain why gods cannot be differentiated while angels can.

If one were to point out that the very method of differentiation of angels is based on their hierarchy of levels which, if existing for gods would by definition render them non-gods (if there is a god on a higher level, the lower god by definition is lacking a quality of godliness) then Rambam's argument is really a different argument – that the existence of multiple gods is impossible because the definition of god entails absolute power and it is impossible for two separate entities to both have absolute power (as discussed by Saadia Gaon in Emunos V'Deios 2:2).

See also Guide for the Perplexed 2:1 where Rambam writes:

> The hypothesis that there exist two Gods is inadmissible, because
> absolutely incorporeal beings cannot be counted (Prop. XVI.), except
> as cause and effect; the relation of time is not applicable to God
> (Prop. XV.), because motion cannot be predicated of Him. ([Friedlander
> translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp088.htm).)

Once again it appears that this argument must necessarily be predicated on the argument of impossibility of two absolute powers. Thus, the argument from the impossibility of distinguishing incorporeal entities should either be insufficient or unnecessary to prove that there is only one god.

Any answers, or flaws/incorrect assumptions in the question?

[I think the [Peirush](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/who-is-the-author-of-the-pirush-on-the-first-four-chapters-of-rambams-hilchos-y) sort of addresses this, but he makes the proof dependent on a different earlier premise, namely, that there can only be one First Cause. If that is the case then once again this specific proof should be either insufficient or unnecessary.]

---

<sup>1.One of the answers challenged this translation, and said that the word here is "godliness" rather than gods. I would therefore note that the Feldheim translation by Moses Hyamson agrees with R. Touger's translation:</sup>

> <sup>If there were plural deities, these would be physical bodies;</sup>

[image: Image of Feldheim translation]

Comment: Corporeal has a narrow sense and a broad sense. The notion of boundaries and corporeality are equivalent at the broad sense. Concept in this point of view has corporeality. Not sure 100%

Comment: I think that the Rambam misspoke in 1:7, and meant to speak about tzuros, Forms, not gufim ugevios. Which is exactly how the Rambam says the various angels -- who have tzuros beli chomer, Form without Substance -- differ and are distinct entities.

But I wouldn't write that in an answer, as there are people who would stone me for saying the Yad contains a misspeech.

Comment: By the way, there is something similar to what I wrote about forms in the Moreh Nevuchim (sec. 2), but in the reverse. He proves there can only be One G-d, and from there that G-d has no Form -- as Form means divisibility, and thus only a wording difference from positing a cooperating pantheon of multiple gods. Just as the Cause has to be One, the Cause can't have parts, or it too would have a Cause.

But again, that's tzurah, not guf.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that angels can be distinguished from each other without a physical manifestation, yet gods cannot be distinguished from each other without a physical manifestation?

[I've quoted your comment, because it appears to me to more succinctly articulate the question]

My answer:

**Equal** essences/existences (מציאות) are separated from each other only through the circumstances associated with body and form. Multiple *equal essences* (שוין במציאותן) cannot coexist incorporeally. Mutiple essences that are not equal in essence can coexist incorporeally. Therefore, gods/divinities (assumed to be equal in essence), cannot coexist incorporeally. Angels, which are NOT equal in their מציאות (their מציאות are hierarchically distinguished in the chain of causation), can coexist.

Answer (score 0):

(As far as I understand)

There are two separate discussions. One discussion is how many gods there are. In that discussion, your points as to the incompleteness of the Rambam's argument, as well as the relevance of Rav Saadia's argument, would apply. That discussion is the topic of the previous halacha in the Rambam, halacha 1:6:

> וכל המעלה על דעתו שיש שם אלוה אחר, חוץ מזה--עובר בלא תעשה
>
> Anyone who considers that there is another god other than This One violates a negative commandment ...

Our halacha is now discussing the G-d, which was already established that He is the only one. Now Rambam ise discussing whether this G-d is one or consists of multiplicity, or parts. Thus Rambam starts this halacha with

> אלוה זה אחד הוא--אינו לא שניים ולא יתר על שניים, אלא אחד
>
> This G-d is one. **He** is not two nor three, rather one

In which the Rambam is discussing the "number," so to speak, of this one G-d.

Rambam continues:

> אילו היו **(ה)אלוהות** הרבה--היו גופין וגווייות
>
> If **Godliness** was many...

The Rambam does not say אילו היו אלוהים הרבה, if there were many gods, but if the concept of G-d were many. In this discussion, differentiating between something which is one unified concept could only be done by the arbitrary distinction of a boundary, or physical distinction. Thus the Rambam negates that possibility.

Comment: This is a nice chiluk, but it hinges on the word being "האלוהות" not "אלוהות". However, the edition I cited from has the text as "אלהות", as do several others. The Frankel edition notes the divergent manuscript evidence, so it's probably inconclusive. However, in the parallel that I cited from The Guide, the only translation that can be read according to your way is the Ibn Tibbon translation. The Qafih and Schwartz translations are pretty clearly referring to multiple gods and not multiple parts of one god, and the Pines and Friedlander translations are absolutely referring to multiple gods.

Comment: @Alex I was actually thinking after I wrote this (before I saw this comment) that the inference from האלהות was completely gratuitous and unnecessary for the point. אלהות with a shuruk anyways means "Godliness." אלהים would be the plural for gods. || I think the rest of my points stand independent of that diyuk anyways || I don't follow your point from the Moreh - he is referring there to multiple absolute beings, not to multiplicity of god.

Comment: As an aside, R' Yaakov Weinberg (who understood this Rambam the same way) said that the Rambam's comment of "and not more than two" (or "and not three" according to some texts) was specifically coming to respond to the Trinity, which (somehow) believes in one god which is three.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced about "אלוהות", especially as R. Touger translates it as "gods" both here, and in 2:10. Also, I'm not entirely convinced that "many gods" vs "many parts of god" is much more than a semantic difference. Most importantly, my point from the Guide is that Rambam there uses the same proof, and there it is clear from most of the translations that he is using it to prove the impossibility of multiple gods.

Comment: @Alex במחילת כבוד R. Touger, as far as I know, the Rambam only uses  אלוהות in two other places, Hil. A.Z. 7:18 and 8:8, in both of which the context is very clearly "elohus" and not "elohos." Everywhere else the plural of gods is אלהים. || The difference is far from semantic - it is the difference between multiple, possibly conflicting beings and there being one being who is not פשוט and does not have ייחוד. (Thus the Rambam in this halacha spends the next lines explaining how Hashem's onenesss is not like other things which are one - because his whole point is distinguishing within oneness).

Comment: @Alex But again I am sorry that I am missing your point from the Moreh. I'll quote the Rambam and you tell me where I am going wrong: ובטל שיהיה שנים או יותר מחמת בטול המנין בדברים הנבדלים אשר אינן גוף אלא אם כן יהיה האחד מהן עלה והשני עלול כפי הנזכר בשש עשרה. וכבר נתבאר שגם אינו נכלל תחת הזמן מפני שהתנועה נמנעת בו כפי שנזכר בחמש עשרה. Rambam explains that there could not be two gods because things without bodies cannot be counted except as one being caused by the other, and since gods have no motion there is no concept of time such that one could be subsequent to the other and still be a ...

Comment: ... god. (That was Qafih's MN.) So Rambam is explaining that there cannot be two independent gods because they can't be both gods and be separate without being subject to time, and gods aren't subject to time. That seems to be proving something different, and with a different proof, than what Rambam is discussing here. Can you please clarify why you think that is related to this Rambam?

Comment: @Y  e  z Avoda Zarah 54b "אלוהות" seems to clearly mean gods, not godliness.

Comment: @Alex a) that is certainly an outlier and b) I still maintain that you won't find it in the Rambam used that way.

Comment: The word היו is plural, so אלוהות must also be plural. There is no way to read the words as you do without changing the text

Comment: I edited the question to add the Feldheim translation by Moses Hyamson which translates it as "deities".

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

> Why is it that angels can be distinguished from each other without a physical manifestation, yet gods cannot be distinguished from each other without a physical manifestation?

is, in general, based upon a false assumption.

You list all these details that Rambam uses to define G-d's uniqueness. Then you look at Rambam using similar language in the context of angels and make the assumption that because of that similar language it can be applied uniformly to either subject, meaning to G-d and to angels. That assumption, that the two subjects are equal, is incorrect.

G-d is not a 'נברא', a created thing or being. G-d always is, was and will be. All of creation, including all categories of angels are נבראים, creations. They have a beginning (and possibly an end). This distinction is the essence of [Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah, 1:1-4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.1.1-4?lang=bi).

By definition, you cannot place the limitations of the creations upon that which transcends creation altogether. This is the meaning of what is found in [Yalkut Shimoni on the Torah 117:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.117.2?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> למה מכנין שמו של הקב"ה וקורין אותו מקום מפני שהוא מקומו של עולם ואין
>   העולם מקומו.

Comment: Can you clarify how this addresses  the question? The question was, if plurality implies corporeality then how can angels be both plural and corporeal? Or expressed reversely, if plurality does not imply corporeality then why can't there be multiple gods?

Comment: @Alex Per your request...

Comment: @Alex It seems he is saying that plurality only implies corporeality for things without beginnings. I don't understand how he knows that though, or why the Rambam didn't state that explicitly

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed. My point was not to say whether the distinction is true or not, only that it doesn't seem to be part of the Rambam's argument.

Comment: @DoubleAA No, that is not what I said. Rambam states there are creations that are not, in and of themselves corporeal. Yet, they are still in the domain of creations. They are not G-d, who transcends all that and is not a creation. To use the vernacular, you are comparing apples to oranges. It doesn't work. And just to clarify for Alex, angels not being corporeal does not  mean they do not interact with the corporeal. This is accomplished by way of the angel dressing in "Garments" which are a mixture of both the corporeal and the non-corporeal.

Comment: @Yaacov Sure what you said is just that God and angels are different kinds. That in itself isn't an answer at all. What I wrote above is a charitable construal of your post which makes it answer the question. And for the record something being a mixture of both corporeal and non corporeal is an oxymoron.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Sorry, I'm still confused. My understanding of the Rambam cited is that something which has plurality must be corporeal because 
 corporeality is the very characteristic that separates individual members of a group into discrete entities. I.e. if there were multiple incorporeal gods, then calling them *multiple* gods is just a semantic trick; it's just one incorporeal entity. Are you disagreeing with my understanding?

Comment: Perhaps this is more clearly shown in a quote that I didn't include in the question. From *Guide for the Perplexed* (Introduction to Book II, Proposition XVI): *Incorporeal bodies can only be numbered when they are forces situated in a body; the several forces must then be counted together with substances
or objects in which they exist. Hence purely spiritual beings, which are neither corporeal nor forces situated in corporeal objects, cannot be counted, except when considered as causes and effects.*

Comment: @Alex I appreciate your struggle & perseverance trying to understand what Rambam is saying in the Mishnah Torah. Reading your last 2 comments, it sounds to me like you are overlooking a general principle. The MT is written progressively, meaning proper comprehension of a later halacha is dependent upon proper comprehension of what precedes it. In your case here, those first 4 laws I pointed to is what you are missing. Your question is trying to evaluate only in terms of what Mekubbalim would describe as ‘Shem Elokim’. Your focus needs shift to ‘Shem Havaya ‘.

Comment: In other terms, you need to focus and reflect on the concept of transcendence. In particular in the context of nomenclature used in Torah for this aspect, like ‘Ain Sof’, ‘Bli Gevul’ & ‘Gevul’, etc. The Jewish philosophers say that the Jewish relationship to G-d, their perception & comprehension, is via ‘Shem Havayah’. The transcendent aspect of G-d. The nations relationship, perception, is via ‘Shem Elokim’. Your question is only rooted in ‘shem Elokim ‘. I would resist the urge to try to use the Guide to understand the Mishnah Torah. The Guide is addressing Greek philosophy/religion (Elokim)

Comment: You might want to look at Pardes Rimonim of the Ramak, erech: Ain Sof.

Comment: So it is better to try to understand Rambam by studying kaballah than by studying *Guide for the Perplexed*?

Comment: It’s better to understand a book of Jewish law, which is based upon Jewish understanding and comprehension by using other Jewish sources based upon that same understanding. The Moreh Nevuchim, as Rambam and his supporters explain, is not speaking to that audience. The language and views are tailored specifically to those ‘confused’ Jews who in his day had assimilated to a view of the Greeks. They didn’t know what the Jewish view was. They equated Greek philosophy with the wisdom of the Torah.

Answer (score 0):

**The Unity of God**

Maimonides felt that G-d's immateriality was proof of His Oness. Maimonides explains:

> This G-d is one; He is neither two nor more than two; He is simply
> one. His unity is not like any other oneness that exists in the world.
> His is not the unity of a kind that encompasses many other single
> particulars; and it is not like the unity of a body that is divided
> into parts and extremities; rather it is a unity that is entirely
> unlike any other sort of oneness in the universe. (MT, Hilkhot Yesodei
> HaTorah, 1:7)

Maimonides refutes the notion of multiplicity in G-d in favor of G-d’s transcendence. For G-d to be multiple He wold have to be material. A notion Maimonides strongly rejects. Maimonides explains:

> If G-d were many, He would have a body and physicality, because items
> that are co-extensive with each other cannot be counted as distinct
> from one another except through occurrences that happen to their
> bodies. (MT, Hilkhot Yesodei HaTorah, 1:7)

And:

> If the Creator had a body, He would have a defined form for it is
> impossible that there should be a body that is not defined. And
> anything that is defined is limited in its power. (MT, Hilkhot Yesodei
> HaTorah, 1:7)

**Angels**

Maimonides did not understand angels as commenly understood. Howard Kreisel explains:

> The separate intellects, together with the celestial spheres and the
> natural existents and forces of the sublunar world, are the “angels”
> spoken of in the Bible and in rabbinic literature according to
> Maimonides. The only existents not considered by him to be angels are
> the “angels” as they are literally depicted. Such creatures do not
> exist in his ontology. Maimonides considers the biblical and rabbinic
> descriptions of the angels to be imaginative representations,
> primarily of the separateintellects. (“Moses Maimonides,” in
> History of Jewish Philosophy, 1997, 255).

Maimonides writes:

> “This is also the view we meet in all parts of Scripture; every act
> of G-d is described as being performed by angels [emphasis added]. But
> ‘angel’ means ‘messenger’; hence every one that is entrusted with a
> certain mission is an angel. Even the movement of the brute creation….
> It is also used of ideals, perceived by prophetic visions, and of
> man’s animal powers…. [F]or natural forces and angels are identical.
> How bad and injurious is the blindness of ignorance!” (Guide, 2:6).

Thus, He explains that the term “angel” refers to the “natural forces.”
He did not belive in winged intermediaries. His depersonification of biblical anthropomorphisms in angels is an attempt to show his correct vision of Judaism which is solely monotheistic.

Comment: I’m not sure how this addresses the question, namely, how can there be many angels if they are not corporeal? Or if it’s possible for something incorporeal to be many, why can’t God be many?

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your comments. In the answer, I tried to show Rambam's explanation in MT, 1:7, that G-d cannot be many by definition. And the answer shows Rambam's depersonification of angels. The angels are not corporeal beings but separate intellects, the “natural forces.” But with regards to G-d's incorporeality, that is another matter.

Comment: The question is the same whether angels are are natural forces or not.

Comment: @Alex Yes, I think the OP was asking if multiple angels exist why can't there be multiplicity in G-d. The first part of the answer answers this question well, I think.

Comment: The one asking the question was me. The crux of the question is that Maimonides proves God's lack of multiplicity from the fact that He is incorporeal. This apparently means that it is impossible to be simultaneously incorporeal and multiplicious. Yet then he says that angels are incorporeal yet also multiplicious, and their multiplicity is distinguished by something other than corporeality. So which is it? If you can be incorporeal and also multiplicious then how did he prove that God is not multiplicious? And if you can't be incorporeal and also multiplicious then how are angels both?

Comment: @Alex Good question. I think the Rambam understood angels as the “natural forces.” This implies that even good people can be considered angels, which are corporeal. An angel according to Maimonides is anything that does the will of G-d. G-d, on the other hand, is the Creator, transcendent, and One. An analogy is the president of the United States, albeit corporeal. There is only one president, but every American who is loyal is a patriot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115744/discussion-between-alex-and-turk-hill).

Answer (score -2):

I think that Maimonides felt that angels were simply natural forces such as rain, wind, and snow. To see a full description of angels, please see my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/111024/19691). I think he felt strongly that it was philosophically impossible to have a multiplicity of gods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104117/discussion-between-alex-and-jonathan).